# Python Linter says value in method call is missing in patched unittest but test runs properly. Why?

Tags: python, unit-testing, stdout

I have been tinkering with testing of late and I never had to test if a class/function had succesfully printed so I decided to try it out. Now, the test is running correctly, I even have several versions of the test but this particular implementation below is having an error raised by the linter I am using even though the code runs. It says:

> "No value for argument 'mock_stdout' in method callpylint(no-value-for-parameter)"

However the value is being found and run when I run the test with no errors.

Can someone explain why this is so? Is it an error in the linter? Is there a way to optimise my code so that error doesn't show?

```py
    class StringManipulationTwo(object):
        def __init__(self):
            self.s=""

        def getstring(self):
            self.s = input("insert values here")

        def printstring(self):
            print(self.s.lower(),end='')

    @patch('builtins.input', lambda *args: 'testing')
    @patch('sys.stdout', new_callable=io.StringIO)
    def assert_stdout(self, expected_output, mock_stdout):
        xobj = StringManipulationTwo()
        xobj.getstring()
        xobj.printstring()
        self.assertEqual(mock_stdout.getvalue(), expected_output)

    def test_printstringtwo(self):
        self.assert_stdout('testing')
```

Comment: Check the line that says `self.assertEqual`. That's where the error was caused.

Comment: @zixuan the linter is saying no value for argument  for ' test_printstringtwo' and assertEqual. As I mentioned, the code is running and working, so its not an issue of assertEqual

Comment: You are missing needed forth argument `mock_input` in your method definition: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch - "If patch() is used as a decorator and new is omitted, the created mock is passed in as an extra argument to the decorated function."

Comment: @ipaleka I have mocked the input. Its the patch that has builtins.input

Comment: Does linter complain with that argument added?

Comment: @ipaleka if I do that the program doesn't run becausd I now have too many arguments being passed.

Comment: and the linter is still complaining.

Comment: @ipaleka You can literally copy and paste the `sys.stdout`/`StringIO` example from [`unittest.mock.patch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch) and trigger this bogus lint error.

Comment: It looks like this is https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/323.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug/limitation in pylint. (See https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/323 and https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/3108.)

I don't want to globally disable E1120 in pylint since I'd still like the error in other cases, nor do I want to add `# pylint: disable=no-value-for-parameter` for every callsite.

I instead have worked around it by making the supposedly missing arguments optional and then checking that they're supplied at runtime:

```py
@patch('builtins.input', lambda *args: 'testing')
@patch('sys.stdout', new_callable=io.StringIO)
def assert_stdout(self, expected_output, mock_stdout=None):
    assert mock_stdout

    # ...
```